# The attachable property was not found in type 'Popup' in MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a "Popup", I'm getting 3 errors messages:

*The attachable property 'BindingContext' was not found in type 'Popup'.*

*The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Popup'.*

*The attachable property 'Content' was not found in type 'Popup'.*

And I don't know how to resolve it.

**XAML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
             xmlns:areaSelectedDtoModel="clr-namespace:BlaBlaBla.Models.Dto;assembly=BlaBlaBla"
             Size="340,340"
             x:Class="BlaBlaBla.Popup.AreaSelectPopup"
             x:TypeArguments="areaSelectedDtoModel:AreaSelectedDtoModel"
             x:Name="XNameAreaSelectPopupPage"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:BlaBlaBla.Models.View;assembly=BlaBlaBla"
             xmlns:behaviors="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit">

    <xct:Popup.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:AreaSelectPopupViewModel/>
    </xct:Popup.BindingContext>
    <xct:Popup.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <behaviors:ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemSelectedEventArgsConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </xct:Popup.Resources>
    <xct:Popup.Content>
        
        ... Some code ....

    </xct:Popup.Content>
</xct:Popup>
```

**CS Code:**

```
namespace BlaBlaBla.Popup
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AreaSelectPopup : Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup<AreaSelectedDtoModel>
    {

        public AreaSelectPopup(AreaSelectedDtoModel areaSelectedDto)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var bindingContext = BindingContext;
            var context = bindingContext as AreaSelectPopupViewModel;
        }

    }
}
```

**Updates to show the error:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. And I resolved it by cleaning and rebuilding.

And change the `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup<AreaSelectedDtoModel>` to `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup`:

```
public partial class AreaSelectPopup : Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup
```

Pass parameter in the Popup:

```
Dismiss(Object parameter);
```

And get the parameter in the page:

```
var result = await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
```

Comment: After doing your recommendation, it's still the same :(  I'm updating the post to show the errors

Comment: Just change the `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup<AreaSelectedDtoModel>` to `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Popup`. You don't have to use the `<T>`. @JBD

Comment: Yes, It's true. It works, but if I do this the popup will return nothing. And I need to return an object from the popup. :)

Comment: The Popup is inherited from the Popup<T>. And you can use `Dismiss(parameter)` in the popup to return the object. @JBD